# How does one use ColorDelegator in from Python IDLE?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, syntax-highlighting, python-idle, python-3.5

I have been developing an IDE for Python, and I have been wondering about saving myself a lot of time by integrating the colorDelegator module from IDLE.

Is it possible to make use of it, and how would I go about doing so? (with the tkinter text widget).

Comment: If you use anything in `idlelib` other than the entry points, be aware of the warning in current versions of idlelib/__init__.py: "The other files are private implementations.  Their details are subject to change.  See PEP 434 for more.  Import them at your own risk."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the example that is at the bottom of ColorDelegator.py:

```
def main():
    from idlelib.Percolator import Percolator
    root = Tk()
    root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.quit)
    text = Text(background="white")
    text.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    text.focus_set()
    p = Percolator(text)
    d = ColorDelegator()
    p.insertfilter(d)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually worked it out myself last night, but thank-you.

Comment: That function was a human-checked (non-automatic) sanity-test, It was renamed `_color_delegator` and edited in summer 2014 when it was incorporated into the then new human-checked htest system.

Comment: @BryanOakley Can you please explain how it works because right now I have a bug that disappears when I comment the `p.insertfilter(d)` but have no idea what `idlelib` is actually doing. I might have changed something inside the files I copied from `idlelib`

Comment: @TheLizzard: sorry, I can't help. I've never used ColorDelegator or idlelib. This answer was just pointing out that ColorDelegator.py comes with an example of how to use it.

Comment: Oh, ok. I am trying to modify `idlelib` to solve the problem of syntax highlighting using already created methods that are supposed to be efficient. I think I might have to reinvent the wheel. Also there is no documentation on how `idlelib` actually works

Comment: @TheLizzard: I doubt that idlelib was ever designed to be used outside of idle. I don't really know, though. There does seem to be some useful code in there.